# Need advices for Activity and Service behavior

Tags: android, service, android-activity

My question is rather theoric, in fact I already saw examples on how to bind or how to start an Activity with a service but I still don't get one thing:
I wrote a Service that is bounded to an activity and I'm wondering how to get the activity that called the bindService() method from this service.
 
My purpose is to get an object that will be necessary to the service because I want it to listen for networks messages in background, as this object is quite complicated to parcel I'd rather get the activity that contains it.
Is there any call possible to the current context?

Thanks for your answers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your service is only used within your application and by only one process at a time, you can try to use a bound service. in the `IBinder` interface used to communicate between the activity and the service implements a public method that returns the local service. This `IBinder` will be given to the activity through the `onServiceConnected()` callback. At this point the activity can get the `Service` object and call on it a public method to pass the object that you want.

```
public class MyService extends Service {

    private final IBinder mBinder = new MyBinder(); //singleton

    private MyObject mObject;

    public class MyBinder extends Binder {
        MyService getService() {
            return this;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
        return mBinder;
    }

    public void setMyObject(MyObject mObject) {
      this.mObject = mObject;
    }
}
```

Hope this works for you.

Comment: it was a very simple and useful answer, thank you very much, btw do you have an idea about how to wake up an activity that is not in foreground from the service?

Comment: The best way is to use an explicit intent like startActivity(bundle,MyActivity.class).

Comment: Isn't start activity only used to run an activity for the first time? if , admit that the user runs the application and then goes to the home, I want my service to listen to a socket and catch an incoming message, display it when the app runs in background or not, using that would be the best way to make it appear again in foreground?
Sorry, first time I use services in android

Comment: Yes and no! By default a new activity is started independently from the previous one. But you can override this behavior in two way. Using the launchmode attribute in your <activity> tag in the manifest. Or you can add a flag to the intent. The first one is to define your activity default behavior and you should use singleTask. The second one is to define your activity behavior in response to THAT particular intent and I think FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK should do the work. Check this out for more information: developer.android.com/guide/components/tasks-and-back-stack.html#ManagingTasks

Comment: It worked fine thank you, I used the Manifest solution with the launchmode setted on singleTask, though it took me a lot of time to get the whole thing.